# How to Sync Evolution Tasks and Notes Using Syncevolution

Tags: 14.04, sync, evolution

I've installed syncevolution and sync-ui and configured my memotoo account. Memotoo is set up to sync calendar, contacts, tasks, and notes. Calendar and contacts sync perfectly, but tasks and notes do not sync. Any suggestions?

Ubuntu 14.04 LTS